# htaccess works with www.example.com but not example.com

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, ghost

I have installed Ghost, which needs nodejs to run. I'm doing this on an Apache Linux server via managed hosting. They kindly let me login with SSH access so I've been able to setup nodejs and Ghost using the standard installation instructions. I installed ghost to the root of my domain so in normal operation someone would go to example.com and it'll show them my blog. Well that's what I'd hoped.

However now when I've come to load Ghost in my browser I discover because I'm accessing it the way I am, and that Ghost doesn't do server configuration, I seem to need an htaccess file to be able to make the site reachable.

So, I have created this htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:65515/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:65515/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>
```

With that saved to the root, if I go to example.com/ghost (the admin panel for Ghost) it works. Nothing wrong there, looks great. If however I try and visit the root, ie goto example.com, instead of showing me the index, it shows me index.js - that is, it literally loads the contents of Ghost's index.js file and displays it instead of parsing it and displaying the main index of the website.

IF however I go to www.example.com then it all works. So whatever the problem is it's because I'm not using www. in the domain.

I would prefer it to work both with or without the www in the URL though. I did try adding some solutions to redirect non-www requests to www.example.com to th ehtaccess but for some reason it still doesn't work (as in if I type example.com it doesn't redirect me to www.example.com).

Comment: Just to clarify, is the "RewriteRul-e" in the last line just a typo in your question?

Comment: Yea, I'll correct it.

Comment: Doing some selective deleting I've found that the first rewriterule is possibly the culprit here. Though again I don't know why.

If I delete the first rewrite rule and save, when I load the ghost admin by going to example.com/ghost/ it still works. Simply going to example.com/ still doesn't work. So that first rewrite rule isn't doing anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's starting to sound like you might have an issue with the Ghost config rather than the htaccess rules. But, just considering the rewrite rules, how come you're checking if the requested file and the requested directory both don't exist? If you're simply using apache to proxy requests through to another port, wouldn't one catchall rule suffice? Like, just "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:65515/$1 [P]"?

Comment: I dunno. I'm really not proficient with editing the htaccess hence why I'm having so much trouble with it I suppose.

Sure enough if I just have it set to that one line then it works (well, it works as www.example.com). I've checked my ghost config several times too. You set the url path in it and I originally set it to http:// example.com and I'ver since changed it to http:// www.example.com and restarted Ghost but it doesn't make any difference. The blogs accessible from the www. domain but not without it (and yet the admin panel is).

It's confused the hell out of me.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you should be using mod_proxy rather than mod_rewrite. At least, that's what I've used in the past. Apache will catch requests coming in on port 80 and then redirect them to port 65515 where your node server is listening.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Like this:

`ProxyPass / http://localhost:65515/`

Comment: Yeah, right. Apparently the [P] does push the request through mod_proxy. Sorry, I'll probably delete this answer. I'll comment on your original question for some clarification though.

Comment: I just checked a previous setup. I just had one line: "ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/"

Comment: Thanks. Tried using just proxypass but it doesn't work at all. The Ghost admin gives me a 404 error with that and the index.js just carries on loading the contents of the file.

Comment: I have discovered that if I visit www.example.com, it works fine. Not sure how I missed this obvious fact but I'm in the habit of always just typing the domain without www. I have edited my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Wasn't anything to do with htaccess, or Ghost or nodejs or anything like it. No, instead the problem was the sodding server was caching the website. I discovered the setting to delete the cache and it all started working fine, so, this is now solved.